# Scrum vs. Agile vs. CMMI

Tags: visual-studio-2013, agile, scrum, tfs-process-template, cmmi

I am pushing my project over to Visual Studio Online in order to have some source control.  I am developing this project by myself.  I have never used Scrum, Agile, nor CMMI before, and the detailed description I [read seems to assume a lot of knowledge](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/vstudio/ms400752.aspx).  (It makes no sense to someone who doesn't already know what they are talking about.)

The best way for me to really learn Scrum or Agile or CMMI is by using them.  But where to start?  The above link does not help me there.

As a solo developer who is just looking for source control, should I start off with Scrum, Agile, or CMMI?

To take the opinion-basedness out of this question, I will make my official question:

**What is the difference between Scrum, Agile, and CMMI in Layman's terms?**

(But really, I just am trying to figure out where to start!)

Comment: "As a solo developer who is just looking for source control, should I start off with Scrum, Agile, or CMMI?" wat? What have those things to do with eachother?

Comment: Sorry...Visual Studio Online forces me to choose one off the bat in order to use their source control (from http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/vstudio/ms400752.aspx) ...no clue which to pick, and their descriptions don't really help a newb like me.

Comment: Perhaps this question belongs somewhere else now that I come to think of it...not really a programming question.

Comment: You (and microsoft) are combining source control with project management and creating a lumpy bowl of stew.  If all you want is source control, I'd start out with git or svn.

Comment: Thanks bcrist, but I have used git. im actually trying to branch out a bit and become comfortable with some professionally used stuff

Comment: This sentence doesn't make sense since git (and svn mainly) is professionally used stuff.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you just wish to use the source code control, it won't make any difference which of those templates you use.

Because VSO forces you to choose, I'd be inclined to select Agile. This is because you're a lone developer whereas scrum is intended for a scrum team.

(I've not used CMMI so cannot comment on that)

Comment: CMMI isn't a process by itself, but a model to analyze and improve processes. Leave it to Microsoft to mix those up.